# Page Block color not working

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to change pageblock color using javascript. it is not getting changed getting error colorPageBlock is not defined in the console. please advise.

```
 <script>
      function colorPageBlock(pageblock, color) {
           if (pageblock != null) 
               pageblock.firstChild.style.cssText = “background-color: ” + color + “;”;
      }
 </script>


<apex:pageBlockSection id = "pbc" title="SELECT INFORMATION">
     <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.LSS1__c}"/><br/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.LSS2__c}"/><br/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.LSS3__c}"/>

     <script>
         colorPageBlock(document.getElementById("{!$Component.pbc}"), "red");
    </script>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score 0):

It must required to assign ID for all parent & child elements. 
Otherwise, it will take random auto generated ID. Like this way,  **pg:frm:j_id106:j_id107**

Maintain ID for all parent-child elements. It works correctly.

- apex:page
- apex:form
- apex:pageBlock
- apex:pageBlockSection

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page id="pg">
<script>
    function colorPageBlock(pageblock, color) {
        if (pageblock != null) 
            pageblock.firstChild.style.cssText = "background-color:" + color + ";";
    }
</script>
<apex:form id="frm">
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbc" title="SELECT INFORMATION">
            <apex:outputLabel value="1"/><br/>
            <apex:outputLabel value="2"/><br/>
            <apex:outputLabel value="3"/><br/>
            <script>
                colorPageBlock(document.getElementById("{!$Component.pg.frm.pb.pbc}"), "red");
            </script>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Page Preview**

[image: Page Preview]
Hope, above will work for you!